# How can I replace the Select ... by Select an option in a react multi select?

Tags: reactjs, select, bootstrap-4, multi-select, bootstrap-select

Hello I would like to change the Select ... by Select an option in a react multi select

Here is a screen :

[image: Select]

And here is my code :

```
<Select
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    isMulti
    options={colourOptions}
    styles={colourStyles}
  />
```

The full code is there :

[full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-rvs7o?file=/example.js:1368-1476)

How can I do that ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but I believe you're asking how to replace the standard placeholder of "Select..." with whatever you want. If so, use the `placeholder` prop. Here is how:

```
<Select
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    isMulti
    options={colourOptions}
    styles={colourStyles}
    placeholder={"Select anything you want..."}
  />
```